# Increasing Window room in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dpi, android-studio

I am running Android Studio 1.4.1 on my Windows 7 machine, which has a 768p resolution display. *The IDE on this resolution looks very congested* and it becomes harder to develop while other 'required' windows in the IDE are open. For example, if preview pane is open while writing UI code in XML, it makes it very difficult to have enough room to write code and look at its output at the same time in the preview pane.

To overcome this issue, I tried decreasing the **DPI** of the display from *96 to 80* using a registry hack, so that the window will shrink and I'll have more room inside the IDE. The registry hack affected the OS windows and font size, but the `IDE seems agnostic of the DPI changes`.

Is there a way to enforce these DPI changes onto the IDE?